How to use innerText instead innerHTML by using the method getAgGridData?
getAgGridData returns me the value from innerHTML attributes which contains the carriage return(\r\n), I would only need to verfy the value from innerText without '\r\n' as showing the webpage. How can I implement it?
cy.get('@AG-Table')
  .should('be.visible')
  .getAgGridData()
  .then((data) => {
    cy.agGridValidateRowsExactOrder(data, expectedTable);
  });

Assertion error:

Expected:[{"Description":"Tick size - Invalid fields}]
Actual:  [{"Description":"Tick size\r\n- Invalid fields}]


Add a line to replace the \r\n with empty string. Use JSON.stringify() to get all parts of the data object without fuss.
.then((data) => {
  const data2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data).replace(/\r\n/g, ''))
  cy.agGridValidateRowsExactOrder(data2, expectedTable);
})


Not sure if there is direct api, you can try below method to see if it works.
// Assuming you have an instance of the grid API
var gridApi = gridOptions.api;

// Function to get all grid data without carriage returns
function getAllGridDataWithoutCR() {
  var rowData = [];
  gridApi.forEachNode(function(node) {
    rowData.push(node.data);
  });
  // Process rowData to remove carriage returns if necessary
  rowData = rowData.map(row => {
    for (let key in row) {
      if (typeof row[key] === 'string') {
        // Replace carriage returns and new lines
        row[key] = row[key].replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
      }
    }
    return row;
  });
  return rowData;
}

// Call the function to get the processed data
var cleanData = getAllGridDataWithoutCR();
console.log(cleanData);

